# Show that $\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}$ is unbiased for $\theta$.

Tags: statistical-inference, order-statistics

Let $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ be a random sample from an arbitrary statistical model $X\sim f_X(x;\theta)$ such that $\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty$, $\mathbb{E}(X)=\theta$. Consider the statistic $\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}$. Show that this is unbiased for $\theta$.

I tried to do the exercise in this way:

Let's compute the distribution of the minimum:

\begin{align}
  F_{X_{(1)}}(x) & =\mathbb{P}(X_{(1)}\leq x)\\
& = \mathbb{P}(\min(X_1,\dots,X_n)\leq x)\\
& =1-\mathbb{P}(\min(X_1,\dots,X_n)\geq x)\\
& = 1-\mathbb{P}(X_1\geq x,\dots,X_n\geq x)\\
& =1-[1-\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)]^n=1-[1-F_{X}(x)]^n.
\end{align}

So that its density function is:

\begin{equation}
 f_{X_{(1)}}(x)= n[1-F_{X}(x)]^{n-1}f_X(x).
\end{equation}

Let's now compute the distribution of the maximum:

\begin{align}
  F_{X_{(n)}}(x)&=\mathbb{P}(X_{(n)}\leq x)\\
& = \mathbb{P}(\max(X_1,\dots,X_n)\leq x)\\
& =\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x,\dots,X_n\leq x)\\
& =[\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)]^n\\
& =[F_{X}(x)]^n.
\end{align}

So that its density function is:

\begin{equation}
 f_{X_{(n)}}(x)= n[F_{X}(x)]^{n-1}f_X(x)
\end{equation}

Hence:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\biggl(\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}\biggr) & =\frac{1}{2}\int\biggl\{xf_{X_{(1)}}(x)+xf_{X_{(n)}}(x) \biggr\}dx \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\int\biggl\{nx[1-F_{X}(x)]^{n-1}f_X(x)+nx[F_{X}(x)]^{n-1}f_X(x)\biggr\}dx \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int\biggl\{nxf_X(x)\biggl[[1-F_{X}(x)]^{n-1}+[F_{X}(x)]^{n-1} \biggr]\biggr\}dx.
\end{align}

And here I get stucked! I don't know how to solve this integral in order to get $\theta$! If I manage to prove that $[1-F_{X}(x)]^{n-1}+[F_{X}(x)]^{n-1} =\frac{2}{n}$ I obtain my result but I don't know how to prove it! Someone can help me? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The estimator $\dfrac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}$ is not an unbiased estimator of $\theta$. For example, if $f(x;\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}$ for $x \ge 0$ then
$$E[X_{(1)}] = \frac{\theta}{n},$$
and
$$E[X_{(n)}] = \theta\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}.$$
It is easy to verify that, for $n >2$, 
$$\frac{E[X_{(1)}]+E[X_{(n)}]}{2} \neq \theta.$$

Comment: So is the exercise wrong in the text? I already asked this to the professor and he checked in the textbook..

Comment: @Al3 I've given you a very famous distribution that shows that the estimator is a biased one. For $n=2$, the estimator is unbiased, of course.